# Showing a series converges absolutely iff it has a uniform bound

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[image]

First I assume that it converges absolutely, so $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n |z_k|$ converges, which means its sequence of partial sums converges. How can I get a statement about this $ M > 0$ upper bound from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that if $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geqslant 1}z_n$ converges absolutely $$\sum_{n=1}^k|z_n|\leqslant \sum_{n\geqslant 1}|z_n|=M<+\infty$$ for each $k$. For the converse use the Monotone Convergence Theorem: every monotone sequence that is bounded converges.

Comment: oho wow, that's simple. So just let lim of our assumed convergence sequence be M, and we automatically have a bound.. thank you! onto part 2: assume that we have the bound then show convergence.

Comment: it's clear our sequence is bounded, but how do we know it is monotone?

Comment: @terribleatmath Summing nonnegative terms $|z_k|\geqslant 0$ can only **increase**  the sum.

Comment: ah, you are correct, thank you. I was thinking of it incorrectly.